# Unable to install Apricity OS along side Windows 10

Tags: partition, windows, system-installation, dual-boot

I'm trying to install Apricity with its GUI installer.

When I get to the partition section, I set up my partitions, and hit "next".

Then a window pops up saying :

```
An EFI system partition is necessary to start Apricity.

A partition was configured with mount point /boot/efi but its esp flag is not set.
To set the flag, go back and edit the partition.

You can continue without setting the flag but your system may fail to start.
```

I then go back and double click the `/boot/efi partiton` to edit it, and check the box for the esp flag. I then click okay to close the "Edit Existing Partition" window. But if I reopen it, the flag is unchecked, and I get the same error.

Comment: Did you check your EFI BIOS settings?

Comment: Have you tried to proceed? Or did your system tell you it wrote the changes to disk **and** reloaded the partition table? Often installers wait with writing the changes until a final installation ok is given, and even if they don't special action would need to be taken to update the Live OS in-memory idea of the disc partitioning.

Comment: I tried proceeding and I got an error which i did not record (something to do with a failed command, I remember seeing "EFI"). That led to my Windows not booting anymore. Which is now fixed, sorry for the delay.

Comment: Is the main issue resolved or just your Windows?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. U meant that now Windows boots again.